# Check last modified directory

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos, server

I would like to execute a command on my Linux (like "find") to list all directories which contents were modified in the last N minutes.

For example, I have a directory "/sites" with at least 300k files/subdirectories in it. I need to run a very fast and optimized command that lists the directories that have files that were modified in the last N minutes.

The command below lists all files that were modified in the last minute (which is great) but takes at least 3 minutes to run:

```
find /sites/ -type f -mmin -1
```

This command below is much faster, it takes no more than 5 seconds! But for some reason the results are not consitent cause this command does not list all directories that had files changed inside of it. Some directories are missing, I have no idea why.

```
find /sites/ -type d -mmin -1
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: it would be nice to have an internal command that is optimized... I thought that in ext3 when a file is updated all the directories above it will have the modified date changed too...

Comment: I believe my last comment was very wrong and removed it (just tested with `ls -alh`).. what happens if you make find run separately for each of the top level directories, e.g. something similar to this, `for i in /sites/; do find $i -type d -mmin -1; done;` same result?

Comment: Also, could it be that the directories had files changed between the time you ran the find command and the time you checked the contents of the directory?

Comment: @Clayton I will test your code when I get to my server ok? But I executed my "find" code way after any file was changed so the directory should be printed.

Answer (score 0):

> This command below is much faster, it takes no more than 5 seconds!
>   But for some reason the results are not consitent cause this command
>   does not list all directories that had files changed inside of it.
>   Some directories are missing, I have no idea why.
>
> ```
> find /sites/ -type d -mmin -1
> ```

It is simply because this command finds only directories that have been changed, and changing in place the content of a preexisting file within a directory does not require the content of the directory (file names and inode numbers) to be changed.
So, to find *the directories that have files that were modified*, it's indispensable to check modification dates of individual files, but we can cut the process short by proceeding to the next directory once a modified file is found in the current one; unfortunately, this is not quite efficient with `find`:

```
find /sites/ -type d -exec find {} -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mmin -1 -ls -quit \;
```

(This lists the first recently modified entry, if any, in each directory.)

If this is not quick enough, a specialized little C program would be in order.